# Find the orthogonal projection of the polynomial onto subspace of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

In the space of polynomials of degree at most 2 over the field of complex numbers, the given scalar product:
$$(f(x),g(x)) = f(1)\overline{g(1)} + 7f(i)\overline{g(i)} + 7f(-1)\overline{g(-1)}$$
Find the orthogonal projection of the polynomial $$1 + 7ix + x^2$$ onto a subspace of polynomials whose root is 1

So I found a basis of this subspace. It's x-1 and x(x-1). And I don't have any idea what should I do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, apply [Gramm-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)  to your basis, thereby getting an orthogonal basis $\{e_1,e_2\}$. Then, compute$$\langle1+7ix+x^2,e_1\rangle e_1+\langle1+7ix+x^2,e_2\rangle e_2$$and you'll have the answer to your question.

Comment: Can you explain, why it will be the  orthogonal projection of the polynomial onto a subspace of polynomials whose root is 1,please?

Comment: Because if $\{e_1,\ldots,e_N\}$ is an orthnormal basis of a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$ endowed with an inner product, the orthogonal projection of a vector $v$ on $W$ is $\sum_{k=1}^N\langle v,e_k\rangle e_k$.